# If I purchased old hunters dlc on one profile, can I play it on a different one?

Tags: bloodborne

Recently I purchased the bloodborn the old hunters dlc on one profile, but when I'm on my other profile, it doesn't say I've purchased or installed it.  I just need to know if the dlc I bought on one profile can be used on my other profile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the DLC should be available on your other profile.

You need to set the profile that **bought** the DLC, as a primary profile. Therefore all profile on the same console can gain access to the DLC.

To set as primary profile:
(Must be done using the profile who owns the DLC)

```
Settings > PSN > Set as Primary Account
```

Comment: how can I be sure that the other account has the DLC activated?

Comment: By Primary do you mean the master account ?